# Excel 2010 - apply same formatting as header cell

Tags: excel

Tried the search but didn't get any useful results.

In excel 2010, if I have a header row containing 200 columns, and the first cell of each column in the first row is formatted in a different way - how do I quickly copy the formatting down to other cells in the same column?

e,g,

row 1 -- F1 F2 F3 F4.................F2000
row 2 -- V1 V2 V3 V4.................V2000
row 3 -- X1 X2.......................X2000

How do i quickly copy the formaating from F1 onto V1, X1, similarly F2 onto V2, X2...without doing that for each column?

I have drop down cell values/lists and formulae in some cells - there are not being applied if I follow this approach? e.g. F1 has a formula = F2+F3; and F4 has a drop down list. How do I copy them 'downwards in their own column'?

Thanks
J

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the 200 header cells.
2. Drag down over the cells you want to format.  The data will be overwritten with the header text.
3. At the bottom right of the area you just autofilled, there will be a small `Auto Fill Options` icon.  Click it, and select `Fill Formatting Only`

At this point, the cells will regain their data values, but retain the formatting of the cells you dragged over them.

That said, this isn't really a programming question, shouldn't this be on Superuser?

Comment: Hmm Sorry I should have clarified better. I have drop down cell values/lists and formulae in some cells - there are not being applied if I follow this approach? e.g. F1 has a formula = F2+F3; and F4 has a drop down list. How do I copy them 'downwards in their own column'?